# mui/x-date-pickers version 6.x question: how to customize year & month format on date picker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon} 
                     adapterLocale={"ja"} 
                     localeText={jaJP.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}>
 
<DatePicker
 {...field}
 label="testlabel"
 slotProps={{
   textField: { variant: "outlined", name: "testDate" },
   toolbar: { hidden: true },
  }}
/>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

with the code above, I get this ↓

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change '6 2023' to '2023 6' ??
I read through the document but couldn't find the way..

Answer (score 1):

I could change 6 2023 to 2023 6
by adding dateFormats to LocalizationProvider

```
<LocalizationProvider
  dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}
  adapterLocale={"ja"}
  localeText={jaJP.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}
  dateFormats={{ monthAndYear: "yyyy MM" }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no API to override this part of the UI.
You can track the progress here: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/6653